# Android libGDX game highscore implementation with tutorial

Tags: android, libgdx

I have found a great tutorial to implement highscores with mySQL connection.
http://www.ikergarcia.com/en/juego-android-highscores

I have tried to use code, created my SQL database, but Java part is problematic. There aren't included the necessary package imports. I couldn't know, how to determine necessary imports and so code is useless.

Comment: Okay, downvote done....tick! But where is feedback or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using google play services if you want to implement high score. [This is the link](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Google-Play-Game-Services-in-LibGDX). Tutorials are included

However, if you insist in using mySQL I had found some interesting material that may answer your question. I believe that you need to download something.

[libgdx-database-extention](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx-database-extension/) &
[web Service libgdx](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx-users/wiki/DatabaseWebservice)

Comment: I do not have yet a verified Google Developer account.

Comment: Yes, links are great, I have read them already, but they are too generous, too formal.